# Mongodb map reduce issue

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I can't explain how but this is what happens to me:

when I run the following command:

```
db.rating_predictions.mapReduce(
function(){

if (!this.target_infos){return;}
  for (i=0;i<this.target_infos.length;i++){
        var obj = {
        channel_id:this.channel_id,
        target_audience:this.target_infos[i].name,
        day:parseInt(this.time_slot.getDay())
    }
   emit(obj,this.target_infos[i]);
  }},
function(ids,target_infos){
var res={};
res.thousands = 0.0;
res.rating = 0.0;
//print(target_infos.length);
for (var i=0;i<target_infos.length;i++){
    var thousands = parseFloat(target_infos[i].thousand_viewer);
    var rating = parseFloat( target_infos[i].trp);
    if (isNaN(thousands)){
        thousands=0;
    }
    if (isNaN(rating)){
        rating=0;
    }
        res.thousands+=thousands;
        res.rating+=rating;
    //print(i);

    }         
    return res;
}
,
{

out:{inline:true}
}
)
```

The first record in response is:

```
{
"_id" : {
    "channel_id" : ObjectId("53219847091d6601dd000018"),
    "target_audience" : "13-19jaar",
    "day" : 0
},
"value" : {
    "thousands" : 1,
    "rating" : 0.10793
}
}
```

Now I know you must think you need to see data but, open your mind and check this out.
when i run the same query without the channel property in the map.
meaning:

```
db.rating_predictions.mapReduce(
function(){

if (!this.target_infos){return;}
  for (i=0;i<this.target_infos.length;i++){
        var obj = {
        //channel_id:this.channel_id, **this is what i removed**
        target_audience:this.target_infos[i].name,
        day:parseInt(this.time_slot.getDay())
    }
   emit(obj,this.target_infos[i]);
  }},
function(ids,target_infos){
var res={};
res.thousands = 0.0;
res.rating = 0.0;
//print(target_infos.length);
for (var i=0;i<target_infos.length;i++){
    var thousands = parseFloat(target_infos[i].thousand_viewer);
    var rating = parseFloat( target_infos[i].trp);
    if (isNaN(thousands)){
        thousands=0;
    }
    if (isNaN(rating)){
        rating=0;
    }
        res.thousands+=thousands;
        res.rating+=rating;
    //print(i);

    }         
    return res;
}
,
{

out:{inline:true}
}
)
```

I get the following:

```
{
"_id" : {
    "target_audience" : "13-19jaar",
    "day" : 0
},
"value" : {
    "thousands" : 0,
    "rating" : 0
}
}
```

Now I'm very confused, How is it possible that for specific channel_id I got rating>0 for day number 0, and for all channels together i got rating 0

I checked if i got negative values by

```
db.rating_predictions.count({"target_infos.trp":{"$lt":0}})
```

the result was 0.

I'd really appreciate help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out
The res object must have same field as the second param  of reduce function so change the 
names to

```
 var res={};
res.thousand_viewer = 0.0;
res.trp = 0.0;
```